# In Java how to check the soap element tag is present or not in soap message using xpath compile

Tags: java, xml, xpath, soap, xml-parsing

Below is the soap message, I need to check whether employee tag is present with soap1 or not? And then do the further processing.

```
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
<soap1:Employee>
<soap1:Designation>Consultant </soap1:Designation>
<soap1:Department>Finance</soap1:Department>
</soap1:Employee>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the expression

```
fn:boolean(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap1:Employee)
```

as a boolean test result.

As per definition, the path expression will return a nodeset, and it's effective boolean value will be true or false depending whether it is empty.
See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-ebv

Do not forget to configure namespace resolution for the XPath engine.

Comment: I have already tried this expression but Nodeset is empty string.

Comment: Then you are casting the empty nodeset to a string. That is not like casting it to boolean. I edited my answer to ensure this does not happen.